# accesses dataframes from another function inside of a class

Tags: python, function, snowflake-connector

I have a class which contains functions that connect to snowflake (using snowflake connector) and perform data cleaning. My thought was to create multiple functions to do separate data cleaning.

I've defined one variable in a function called "work_data" called "self.calls" and I've defined that function as a pandas dataframe and I'd like to access that dataframe in another function.

Here's my current process:

I first initialized the variable in the **init** function and made it a blank list for now. After I've run the "work_data" function and try and run the "finalized_data" function..but I get the blank list instead of the panadas data frame.

Here's my code so far:

```
class SnowReader:

    sql_pslink ='select * from xyz in xyz";'
    sql_account= 'select * from xyz in xyz;'
    sql_call = 'select * from xyz in xyz;'
    sql_sales = 'select * from xyz in xyz;'
    sql_address = 'select * from xyz in xyz;'

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.database = "xyz"
        self.username = INTEGRATION_USER
        self.password = SNOW_PASSWORD
        self.account = "xyz"
        self.warehouse = "xyz"
        self.role = "xyz"
        self.schema = "xyz"
        self.conn = self._connect_snow()
        self.calls = []

    def _connect_snow(self):
        try:
            self.conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                account=self.account,
                warehouse=self.warehouse,
                database=self.database,
                role=self.role,
                schema=self.schema,
            )

            logger.info("You are connected to Snowflake")
        except Exception as ex:
            if ex.errno == 250001:
                logger.error(
                    f"Invalid username/password, please re-enter username and password.."
                )
                
    def work_data(self):
        if not self.conn:
            self._connect_snow()
        link = pd.read_sql(SnowReader.sql_pslink, self.conn)
        account = pd.read_sql(SnowReader.sql_account, self.conn)
        self.calls = pd.read_sql(SnowReader.sql_call, self.conn)
        sales = pd.read_sql(SnowReader.sql_sales, self.conn)
        Calls_merged = self.calls.groupby('xyz', as_index=False)['xyz'].count()
        Account_step1 = Calls_merged.merge(account,left_on='xyz', right_on='xyz', how="left" )
        Sales_merged = sales.groupby(['xyz'], as_index=False)['xyz'].count()
        Account_final = Sales_merged.merge(Account_step1,left_on='xyz', right_on='xyz', how="left" )
        Master_Address = pd.read_sql(SnowReader.sql_address, self.conn)
        return Account_final, Master_Address, link, self.calls
    
    def finalize_data(self):
        return self.calls


a, b, c, d= SnowReader().work_data()
display(a,b,c, d)
testt = SnowReader().finalize_data()
testt
```

Comment: Please share the code showing how you construct the object from the class and call the methods.

Comment: Could you not just call the dataframe? Please, show exactly where this error is occurring.

Comment: when I run this: testt = SnowReader().finalize_data() and print(test) I get [] . I want to call finalize_data and get the call dataframe (from work_data)